# Cannot Post To Facebook using FBDialogs

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I have use Facebook SDK Framework for post message on Facebook.

I have used native facebook dialog for post message.

```
NSString *msg = @"Sample message for posting...";
BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:msg images:nil urls:nil handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error)
                              {
                                  if (!error)
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"result=%u",result);

                                      if (result == 0) {

                                          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfully posted" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                          [alert show];

                                      }
                                      else if (result == 1) {

                                          NSLog(@"Cancel");

                                      }
                                      else {

                                          NSLog(@"Dialog not supported");

                                      }

                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"Dialog not supported. error");
                                  }

                              }];
```

when I use this code, it successfully open the dialog and when I tap on Post button in native dialog, return result is 0.

But it was not post on Facebook and display following message in alert "Cannot Post To Facebook The post cannot be sent because the connection to Facebook failed in iOS7".

So, how to solve this? why this message is coming ?
[image]

Comment: Do you get any solution or more detail about this problem?

Comment: no I did not get any solution.